# Building Diagram Editor For Logic Diagrams

Tags: angular, d3.js, svg, editor, diagram

I have a requirement to build  web-based a diagram editor(like https://www.draw.io/) where user can place various logic gates(AND, OR, XOR etc) and build their inter relationship. It must have feature like interactive point-and-click, select and connect, drag and drop.

Diagrams should have functionality to be saved in some format for later editing. I want use SVG for scalable graphics and Angular as framework. Technologies in my mind are SVG, d3, Angular5/6 framework. Please suggest some appropriate technologies for the same.
Does any one know of any examples that might point me in the right direction, or who can offer some insight.

Answer (score -1):

The first solution I thought of was [Node-RED](https://nodered.org) -- although it is designed to do **WAY** more than just draw flow diagrams... Its Editor is built using SVG and D3, and once you "deploy" your flow, it begins running immediately. So you *could* actually use it to debug your flow, by injecting known test values, and verifying the outputs.

Here is an example flow that took me all of 5 minutes to create and test:

[image: And/Or logic gate flow]

*N.B. Node-RED is a single user Express (nodejs) application -- so if you must have individual users having different flows/instances, you will need to deploy an instance for each user, either on separate ports or hosts.*

Answer (score -3):

I have very similar requirements. For free I found D3.js, vis.js. Very cheap is http://www.draw2d.org/. A there is several not free products: gojs.net or jointjs.